# Ignore request-mapping for TypeMismatchException on @PathVariable

Tags: spring-mvc

Is there a global configuration-switch where I can tell Spring to ignore the request-mapping if a `TypeMismatchException` occurs on a `@PathVariable`?

E.g.

```
...
@RequestMapping(value="/somepath/*-{someId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String doSomething(@PathVariable Integer someId, Model model)
```

When the mapping is called with a string rather than a number the `TypeMismatchException` is thrown and a 500 is raised.
I don't want to hastle with this in `@ExceptionHandler`s or some ExceptionResolver. Simply don't match (and run into a 404)!

Comment: Not sure what you want. The exception is thrown when the match has already been made and the default behavior of Spring is to return 400 (which is the correct code in this case).

Comment: You can simply match digits with a regex e.g. `"/somepath/*-{someId:\\d+}"`

Comment: @Bart: This is the answer. Can you please post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only want to match digits as the value of `{someId}` your request mapping is to generic. To make it more specific you can use a regex e.g.

`@RequestMapping(value="/somepath/*-{someId:\\d+}")`

The above will only match if the value mapping to `{someId}` is one or more digits.